# Cannot save to Documents folder on Macbook - Permission denied

Tags: mac, permissions

I have recently copied a load of files from a time machine backup to my macbook Documents folder.

I did not copy via the time machine application, but manually copied from the time machine backup folder.

I now cannot write to my Documents folder, unless I use the sudo command - I get a `Permission denied` error.

For example, if I run: `touch ~/Documents/test.txt` I get an error: `Permission denied`

This problem has only occurred since I copied those folders into my Documents folder.

I checked the owner of Documents folder and it is the user I am logged in with.
Can you please advise what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up renaming documents to Documents-old

```
sudo mv Documents Documents-old
```

Then I created a new Documents folder, and moved everything from Documents-old to Documents.
Then I deleted Documents-old, and I can now write to the Documents folder!

Comment: Great that you solved your problem, but in the future to avoid this kind of pain, stick to using the Time Machine app to access the files. While macOS is unix-derived, Apple is not know for making it easy to get at the data stores of their applications.